# Is it possible to change background of a div when checkbox is checked with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Is it possible to change red background of a div when checkbox is checked with jquery.
Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwNFx/)

```
<div class="col-md-4 wizardBox">
<label for="img1">
    <img src="http://beststore.bugs3.com/img/sample/portfolio-macbook.fw.png" />
    <p>Culture</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="img1" id="img1" name="img1" value="" />
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: If one word answers were allowed: Yes.

Comment: Since more than a word is generally required: Of course it is!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/YwNFx/1/

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, your fiddle doesn't change the colour back when the checkbox is unchecked. I'm assuming he needs a toggle based behaviour since it doesn't really make sense UI wise otherwise. :-P

Comment: @Siddharth Yes, I'm not going to make too much effort!

Comment: Indeed, Rob. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#img1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) 
       $('.wizardBox').css('background-color','red');
    else
       $('.wizardBox').css('background-color','');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqB4P/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes...just listen to a change event on the checkbox, and change the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) 
       $(this).closest(".wizardBox").css('background-color','red');
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys but for some reason it won't work with [link](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) . Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is good practice to cache the control in variable

```
//here we getting the control(div) in the variable 
var $div=$('.wizardBox');
$('#img1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) 
       $div.css('background-color','red');
    else
       $div.css('background-color','');
});
```

i have updated the JSFiddle for you 
[click here to see](http://jsfiddle.net/uqB4P/1/)